# Restart Code after Uncaught Exception?

Tags: php

I'm not very smooth with PHP, because I'm only using it temporary. The nature of my code is very simple, and it does have a few cases where it comes to a "uncaught exception: exit".

How exactly can I use the exception handler to tell it restart the code when it gets this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Use `try-catch` statement:

```
try {
    //your code here
} catch (Exception e) {
   // do something if an exception is thrown.
}
```